# The only periodic exponential type functions are trigonometric polynomials.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I read in some papers that entire functions of exponential type which have period $2\pi$ are necessarily trigonometric polynomials. Do you know where I can find a prove of this statement?

Comment: The Context Control Team dropped the ball huh

Answer (score 0):

This is not difficult to prove directly using that an exponential type function without zeroes is $e^{az+b}$ and if it's periodic with period $2\pi$ then $e^{2\pi a}=1$ so $a=in$ and $f(z)=ce^{inz}=c(\cos nz+i \sin nz)$. Similarly if the period is $4\pi$ we get $a$ half integer.

Then assume that $F$ has zeroes and if $A$ is the set of all real numbers $y$ st $f(a+iy)=0$ for some real $a$, we claim that $A$ is finite since if $f$ is exponential type the number of its zeroes in a disc of radius $R$ is at most $cR$ for some $c>0$ but each $y \in A$ gives at least $R/10$ zeroes of abscissa $y$ and absolute value at most $R$ if $R >2(|y|+\pi)$ say since if $a_0+iy, 0\le a_0 <2\pi$ is (by periodicity) the first such zero in the right half plane including the imaginary axis, then all the zeroes $a_0+ 2\pi k+iy, |k| < R/(6 \pi)$ have absolute value less than $R$ and we see that there at least $R/(3 \pi)>R/10$ such, so for large $R$ clearly $A$ cannot have more $10c$ elements

For such an abscissa there are finitely many zeroes $a+iy, 0 \le a < 2\pi$ and let's call the distinct such zeroes $w_1(y), w_2(y),..w_{k_y}(y), k_y \ge 1$; if the order order of each $w_m(y)$ is some $n_m(y) \ge 1$, let $$g(z)=\Pi_{y \in A, k=1,..k(y)}\sin^{n_k(y)} (z-w_k(y))/2$$

Clearly, $g$ vanishes at each $w_k(y)+2n\pi$ and all those are distinct since for those with the same abscissa, the ordinates are distinct by our choices ($w_k(y)+2n\pi=w_l(y)+2m\pi$ implies $m=n, k=l$ since $0<|w_k(y)-w_l(y)| <2\pi, k \ne l$) and it is a trigonometric polynomial in $z/2$ by writing the $2i\sin(z)=e^{iz}-e^{-iz}$ and multiplying.

But $f/g$ then is still an exponential type function and now without zeroes (and period either $2\pi$ or $4\pi$) so $f=cge^{\pi iaz}$ where $a$ is integer or half integer, and we get that $f$ is a trigonometric polynomial in $z/2$ but by $2\pi$ periodicity we easily see that all the terms $c_ke^{i(2k+1)z/2}$ vanish since they transform to the negative when $z\to z+2\pi$ so inducting on the highest such we get that $c_k=0$. Hence $f$ is indeed a trigonometric polynomial in $z$